# How to destroy RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I can use the following code to create a new peer connection object:

```
var peer = new RTCPeerConnection();
```

When this happens, chrome shows it as new connection object in `chrome://webrtc-internals/`

I would like to destroy this object later. How to do it? I tried

```
peer.close();
```

but this does not seem to do anything, since the `peer` variable is still of type RTCPeerConnection and I can still see it active in `chrome://webrtc-internals/`.

If I unset the variable, like

```
peer=false;
```

it still shows it in `chrome://webrtc-internals/`. Yet if I close the webpage then it immediately disappears from `chrome://webrtc-internals/`.

What is the proper way to free the RTCPeerConnection object? I am asking because if I do not free them, I am occasionally getting refusal from web browser to create new RTCPeerConnection because there are too many of them in use.

Answer (score 2):

Actually

```
peer.close();
```

is a right way to do it.

You can also do something like this:

```
peer.close();
peer = null;
```

Here is some snippets from original WebRTC code samples:

```
function hangup() {
  console.log('Ending call');
  pc1.close();
  pc2.close();
  pc1 = null;
  pc2 = null;
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  callButton.disabled = false;
}
```

https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/js/main.js#L175

Comment: Thnank you. I realized that even if I still see many connections in `chrome://webrtc-internals/` even while using .close(), it recognizes them as closed but removes them from the list some time later

Answer (score 1):

on which event you want to destroy it ? 
there maybe a missing part within your code that leave the connection opened 
here is a whole PDF book explaining how WebRtc Works on browsers ,

[click here to download it](https://files.fm/u/f4zgkfas)

i am giving this book to you so you can check if there is any parts of your code that leave the connection open some where on this case even if you closed the peer on that specific event it will still show up and remains on the browser .

As for your question ,assuming that you want to close it from a button click lets call it Hang Up button , 
//hang up

```
hangUpBtn.addEventListener("click", function () { 

send({ 
  type: "leave" 
});

handleLeave(); 
});

function handleLeave() { 
connectedUser = null; 
remoteVideo.src = null; 

yourConn.close(); 
yourConn.onicecandidate = null; 
yourConn.onaddstream = null; 
};
```

When the user disconnects you should clean up its connection. you can delete the user when the close event is fired. Add the following code to the connection handler

```
connection.on("close", function() { 
if(connection.name) { 
 delete users[connection.name]; 
} 
});
```

when the user click on hang button It will send a “leave” message to the other user It will close the RTCPeerConnection and destroy the connection locally

this should close the rtc connection , as far as i remember there is bug on chrome even if you closed the connection it will make leak on the memory not sure if this bug still there .

one more thing when user exits, for example closes a browser window 
this may help if we are still in "offer","answer" or "candidate" state

```
  connection.on("close", function() { 

  if(connection.name) { 
  delete users[connection.name]; 

  if(connection.otherName) { 
  console.log("Disconnecting from ", connection.otherName); 
  var conn = users[connection.otherName]; 
  conn.otherName = null;  

  if(conn != null) { 
  sendTo(conn, { 
  type: "leave" 
  }); 
  }  
  } 
  } 
  });  

  connection.send("Hello world"); 
  });
```

Comment: I do not fully understand why you delete users[something] because there is no such variable in my code. Also I do not have any send() function. Maybe you are thinking of using some rtc framework?

Comment: i was assuming that you are establishing connection between 2 users 
user A & user B  , so when any one of them click on the button hang up , you should delete the connection of user A & B . 
by removing the connection , am using send  { type : leave } to notify the other user about disconnection 
can you give me more details about where you are using the peers on your app ?

Comment: can you share whole code of the page which you having issue with ?

Comment: can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249772/cant-close-connection-beetween-peer-on-peerjs @AhmedSh