# Can't close connection beetween peer on peerjs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, peerjs

I'm trying to make video chat app, and it works with peerjs. Now I want to add some functionality to handle scenarios like if connection is destroyed by user, the other user that connected to him gets a notification.

Here's my code for calling other user:

```js
 call(userId: string, partnerId: string) {
    const conn = this.peer.connect(partnerId);
    conn.on('open', () => {
      conn.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      conn.send(userId);
    })
    if (this.peer.destroyed) {
      this.createPeer(this.userId);
    }

    if (this.myEl.classList.contains('disableCall')) {
      console.log('Show');
      this.myEl.classList.add('showCall');
      this.partnerEl.classList.add('showCall');
      this.myEl.classList.remove('disableCall');
      this.partnerEl.classList.remove('disableCall');
    }
    this.hideCallLogin = false;
    const call = this.peer.call(partnerId, this.myStream);
    this.mediaConnection = call;
    call.on('stream', (stream) => {
      this.partnerEl.srcObject = stream;
      this.hideCall = true;
      this.hideCallLogin = false;
      if (call.peerConnection.connectionState == 'connecting') {
        this.swapVideo('my-video');
      }
    });
    call.on('close', () => {
      console.log('Di hentikan oleh penerima');
      this.mediaConnection.close();
      this.myEl.classList.remove('showCall');
      this.partnerEl.classList.remove('showCall');
      this.myEl.classList.add('disableCall');
      this.partnerEl.classList.add('disableCall');
      this.hideCall = false;
      this.hideCallLogin = false;
    })
  }
```

Here's how other user answers:

```js
wait() {
    this.peer.on('call', (call) => {
      this.mediaConnection = call;
      //change this to a modal for confirm a call
      var acceptsCall = confirm(partner + " is calling, do you want to accept it ?");
      if (acceptsCall) {
        call.answer(this.myStream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
        call.on('stream', (stream) => {
          if (this.myEl.classList.contains('disableCall')) {
            console.log('Show');
            this.partnerEl.classList.add('showCall');
            this.myEl.classList.add('showCall');
            this.partnerEl.classList.remove('disableCall');
            this.myEl.classList.remove('disableCall');
          }
          this.partnerEl.srcObject = stream;
          this.status = 'Connected';
          this.hideCallLogin = false;
          this.swapVideo('my-video');
        });
        call.on('close', () => {
          console.log('Di hentikan oleh penelpon');
          this.myEl.classList.remove('showCall');
          this.partnerEl.classList.remove('showCall');
          this.myEl.classList.add('disableCall');
          this.partnerEl.classList.add('disableCall');
          console.log(this.status);
          this.hideCall = false;
          this.hideCallLogin = false;
        })
      }
    });
    //getting partner id
    let partner = '';
    this.peer.on('connection', (conn) => {
      conn.on('open', () => {
        conn.on('data', (data) => {
          partner = data;
        })
      })
    })

  }
```

What I want is peers disconnect or destroyed if 1 peer hangs up, and it automatically closes their video. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Try comment `disconnect` leaving only `destroy`. Looks like disconnect is not what you needed https://peerjs.com/docs.html#peerdisconnect

Comment: Another thing to try `peer.connect.close()`. Looks like it should be the preferred method of closing connections https://peerjs.com/docs.html#dataconnection-close

Comment: i believe there's no `peer.connect.close()` since connect needs an argument of targetId

Comment: actually i only wanted to close current session you could say, destroy will disconnect all connection to server

Comment: Try using `.close()` on mediaConnection. You get one as an argument for `on('call')` listener

Comment: can you show me how ? place an edit on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
wait() {
  this.peer.on('call', (call) => {
    this.mediaConnection = call; // Save reference to the `mediaConnection` object

    var acceptsCall = confirm("Videocall incoming, do you want to accept it ?");
    if (acceptsCall) {
      call.answer(this.myStream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
      call.on('stream', (stream) => {
        this.partnerEl.srcObject = stream;
        this.status = 'Connected';
        console.log(this.status);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Then when you want to hang up you should be able to call `this.mediaConnection.close()`

### Update 1

To have it working on the caller end you have to store mediaConnection there as well.

```js
call(partnerId: string) {
  this.partnerId = partnerId;
  console.log(this.peer.destroyed);

  if (this.peer.destroyed) {
    this.createPeer(this.userId);
  }
  
  const call = this.peer.call(partnerId, this.myStream);
  this.mediaConnection = call; // Save reference to the `mediaConnection` object

  call.on('stream', (stream) => {
    this.partnerEl.srcObject = stream;
    this.hideCall = true;
    this.hideCallLogin = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: its working for receiver user, but its undefined for caller user

Comment: yes ofc, i place media connection for caller in the wrong place. nice its working, thanks man

Comment: if there's any problem, i'll create other post and and bouty i'll mention you here,thanksagain

Comment: so i try again with your solution,  i have 2 video container, 1 in fullscreen and 1 in picture-in-picture mode. after it disconnect i hide the videos both local video and remote video, and i try to call again, my fullscreen video got blank for a couple seconds, any idea why?

Comment: ah and actually, if user 1 ended the call, videos will be hide, but user 2 is not. i have listen `on.('close')` and add classes to hide but no luck, the videos still showing up

Comment: maybe it because `on('close')` is not fired

Comment: I don't know where you are listening for close event. You shouldn't listening on peer definitely. And as per docs in Firefox this event is yet not supported

Comment: No idea. You could try to listen for 'error' events.

Comment: i try the same method as yours, but for dataConnection, both of the user are listening to dataConnection.on('close') and on hangup i added dataConnection.close() and it works

Answer (score 1):

In case the above solution is not working for you, I have another solution which worked for me. Peerjs library provides data connection to send other types of data. So I created a data connection which you can setup along the `call` method.

Here is some code - `thisPeer` and `otherPeer` are global variables to store reference to the data connection on both clients:

```js
var otherPeer;
var thisPeer;
```

This is the call initiator code:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then((s) => {
      .....

      const call = peer.call(remoteUserId, s);
      thisPeer = peer.connect(remoteUserId);
      thisPeer.on("data", (data) => {
        if (data == "end") {
          thisPeer.close();
          if (peer != null) {
            peer.destroy();
          }
          console.log("the caller ended the call", data);
        }
      });

      call.on("stream", (remoteStream) => {
        .....
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error on starting a call: ", err));
```

This is the call acceptor code:

```js
peer.on("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to other peer");

    peer.on("connection", (conn) => {  // listen for data connection here
      console.log("the caller sent message", conn);
      otherPeer = conn;
      conn.on("data", (data) => {
        if (data == "end") {
          conn.close();
          if (peer != null) {
            peer.destroy();
          }
          console.log("the caller ended the call", data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Finally, either end can use the function `endCall` to close the connection and notify the other end:

```js
function endCall() {
  if (otherPeer != null) {
     otherPeer.send("end");
  }
  if (thisPeer != null) {
     thisPeer.send("end");
  }
  if (peer != null) {
     peer.destroy();
  }
}
```